# `scad-mode` (derived from CC Mode) hangs Emacs. How to debug/fix?

Tags: debugging, cc-mode, derived-mode

I have found that `scad-mode.el`, a derived mode from CC Mode, which can be found here:

https://github.com/openscad/openscad/blob/master/contrib/scad-mode.el

hangs emacs if I type

```
#(
```

into the window, or indeed any line containing a `#` and also one of `()[]{}`.  I have to kill Emacs completely and restart it after this crash.

I'm not familiar with how one write a derived mode and have not been able to figure out why this happens.  I deleted almost all of `scad-mode.el` and I still get the hang.  (This makes me suspect that the hang is caused by something missing rather than something in the code.) Furthermore, I can't find a coherent explanation of how one writes derived modes.  The example derived mode,

http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/derived-mode-ex.el

doesn't look much like `scad-mode.el`.  I wonder if perhaps things have changed since 2002, when the example was written.  The documentation text for `c-basic-common-init` says I need to call `c-init-language-vars` first, which `scad-mode` does not.  But if I add a call to this

```
(c-init-language-vars scad-mode)
```

I get the message:

```
File mode specification error: (void-function c-init-language-vars)
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with `scad-mode.el` that it causes Emacs to hang?  Or how to go about debugging it?

Note: I reduced scad-mode.el to this:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.scad$" . scad-mode))
(require 'cc-mode)
(define-derived-mode scad-mode prog-mode "SCAD"
  "Major mode for editing OpenSCAD code."
  (c-initialize-cc-mode)
  (c-basic-common-init 'scad-mode "k&r")
)
(provide 'scad-mode)
```

and it still hangs the same way.  It's not clear to me how to truly disentangle the question of how to write a mode from the question of why this is hanging.  It has been suggested to me that it's an emacs bug.

Comment: I updated emacs (now at 26.1...not sure what I was at before) and I now have to type "#a=(" to crash emacs in scad-mode.

Comment: If you need to kill it, then it didn't "crash".  You probably mean that it "freezes" or "hangs".  It's most commonly due to a pathological font-lock regexp.

Comment: What @Stefan said. And please separate your multiple questions into separate questions on this site. How to debug your problem, how to define a derived mode, etc. One question per question, please. Thx.

Comment: I agree with @Stefan that font-lock is the most likely culprit. One way to check this is to disable font-lock and type the characters. If Emacs doesn't hang you can run `font-lock-studio` (available from Melpa) to single-step the font-lock keywords to find which is broken.

Comment: I disabled font-lock by doing M-x font-lock-mode and this had no effect on the behavior.  I still get the hang.  I have also discovered that if I hit C-g it escapes from the hang.